# Removing items from array based on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var firstArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var secondArr = [2,3];
```

How can I get an array like this:

```
[1,4,5]
```

I would like to use a solution that could be used when elements of the array are objects with multiple properties.

Comment: If you can use underscore: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @epascarello This question is not about removing duplicates...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

For example:

```
firstArr.filter(function(item){ 
    return secondArr.indexOf(item) === -1; 
});
```

Comment: For OP's second request (array elements are objects), it should be noted that this will only work if *the same* object is present in both arrays, and not just a *copy* of that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Function to remove items.

```
function removeA(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
var ary = ['three', 'seven', 'eleven'];
removeA(ary, 'seven');
```